# How to use following python dictionary in template using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a Python dictionary like this:

```
{'test_data': ['reads_1.fq', 'reads_2.fq'], 'test_data/new_directory': ['ok.txt'], 'hello': ['ok.txt'], 'hello/hi/hey': ['b.txt']}
```

I want to use this in the template(Django) to create a tree structure like:

```
test_data
 reads_1.fq
 reads_2.fq

test_data/new_directory
 ok.txt

hello
 ok.txt

hello/hi/hey
 b.txt
```

How can this be done using javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the dictionary to json first in your view and use javascript to work directly on the json (instead of using django's template language to try and format javascript)

```
# In your view somewhere
import json

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',{ 'my_json': json.dumps(my_dict) }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in your template:

```
<script>
     obj = {{ my_json|safe }};
     for (var prop in obj){  // Iterating through an object
         console.log(prop);
         for(i=0, i < obj[prop].length, i++){  // Iterating through the list for each key
              console.log(obj[prop][i]);
         }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: When I see the data: the data looks like:
ata = {&quot;test_data&quot;: [&quot;reads_1.fq&quot;, &quot;reads_2.fq&quot;], &quot;test_data/new_directory&quot;

Comment: I forgot to add that you need to mark the template variables output as being [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hm. No error is shown. Variable is passed to template too. But I can't see any outputs on the console.

Comment: I've updated the code but it's untested; you'll need to work on the javascript yourself and debug why or why it isn't working. Use the `console.log` to make sure `data` is properly populated. From there it's a simple case of looping through the object and printing it how you like.